# Spring Boot actuator: Why is the Health status of Redis cluster not correct?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a spring boot project with redis cluster configuration using Jedis. The config files are as follows:

application.yml file:

[image]

RedisClusterConfig.java file:

```
@Configuration
```

public class RedisClusterConfig {

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Value("${redis.cluster.host1}") private String HOST1;
@Value("${redis.cluster.port1}") private Integer PORT1;

@Value("${redis.cluster.host2}") private String HOST2;
@Value("${redis.cluster.port2}") private Integer PORT2;

@Value("${redis.cluster.host3}") private String HOST3;
@Value("${redis.cluster.port3}") private Integer PORT3;

@Value("${redis.cluster.host4}") private String HOST4;
@Value("${redis.cluster.port4}") private Integer PORT4;

@Value("${redis.cluster.host5}") private String HOST5;
@Value("${redis.cluster.port5}") private Integer PORT5;

@Value("${redis.cluster.host6}") private String HOST6;
@Value("${redis.cluster.port6}") private Integer PORT6;

@Bean
public JedisCluster jedisCluster() {
    Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
    //Jedis Cluster will attempt to discover cluster nodes automatically
    jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort(HOST1, PORT1));
    jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort(HOST2, PORT2));
    jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort(HOST3, PORT3));

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(HOST4)){
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort(HOST4, PORT4));
    }else{
        logger.warn("jedis cluster HOST4 not configured.");
    }

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(HOST5)){
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort(HOST5, PORT5));
    }else{
        logger.warn("jedis cluster HOST5 not configured.");
    }

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(HOST6)){
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort(HOST6, PORT6));
    }else{
        logger.warn("jedis cluster HOST6 not configured.");
    }
    JedisCluster jc = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes, new JedisPoolConfig());
    return jc;
}
```

}

With this config, everything works fine. I can write/read data to/from the redis cluster. But when I access http://localhost:64001/health to get the actuator health status, it returns the result as follows:

{"status":"DOWN","diskSpace":{"status":"UP","total":120031539200,"free":33381117952,"threshold":10485760},"redis":{"status":"DOWN","error":"org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool"},"mongo":{"status":"UP","version":"3.2.3"},"db":{"status":"UP","dataSource1":{"status":"UP","database":"MySQL","hello":1},"dataSource2":{"status":"UP","database":"MySQL","hello":1},"dataSource3":{"status":"UP","database":"MySQL","hello":1}}}

We can see the error hints about Jedis.

BTW, the related dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Is there any thing I may miss to get the /health status back to "UP"? Thanks!

More info:
I traced the startup and found that the RedisHealthIndicator passed a wrong factory with host=localhost and port=6379, which should be the configured cluster hosts and ports?

```
public RedisHealthIndicator(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    Assert.notNull(connectionFactory, "ConnectionFactory must not be null");
    this.redisConnectionFactory = connectionFactory;
}
```

Comment: Please share the exception. `JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool` has always a root cause which is not visible in the post.

Comment: I cannot get the exception details. But I found that during the startup, the following code pass a wrong factory with host is localhost and port is 6379, which should be the cluster host and port: ` public RedisHealthIndicator(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
  Assert.notNull(connectionFactory, "ConnectionFactory must not be null");
  this.redisConnectionFactory = connectionFactory;
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the problem solved by re-config the redis as follows:

`spring:
  redis:
    cluster:
      nodes:
        - 192.168.0.17:6390
        - 192.168.0.17:6391
        - 192.168.0.17:6392
        - 192.168.0.9:6390
        - 192.168.0.9:6391
        - 192.168.0.9:6392`

Comment: What if I am not using a cluster, and a simple local install of Redis. Do I still need to specify `spring.redis.cluster.nodes=127.0.0.1:6379`?

Comment: In that case, I believe you should config it by another way, like: spring.redis.host=localhost, spring.redis.port=6379